# checking the files in local directory

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check the files inside my `Library` folder that is in my project directory. I tried multiple things and I still can't do it dynamically. I can hard code the path but it is the path of my mac.

I know for managing the files system wide you can use `FileManager`, and for the current directory you can use `Bundle`. But I can't check the files and get the names of them in `Bundle` and I can't use simply work with current project files and folder in `FileManager` since it needs path to that

Here's the hard coded part that works:

```
let itemsInDirectory = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/Users/ama25/Documents/Amusica/Amusica/Library")
print(itemsInDirectory)
```

what I tried:

```
let test = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
print(test)
let itemsInDirectory = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: test[0], includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
print(itemsInDirectory)
```

I even tried

```
let test = Bundle.main.resourcePath
```

then inserting it in `contentsOfDirectory`

I have to say I'm still learning about swift and I couldn't find any solution to my question. So if you can help me I will be glad and can you explain what is the solution.

Comment: You would use [`.libraryDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/librarydirectory) to get the url for your app's library directory, not `.documentDirectory`. What files are you looking for in the library folder of your installed app?  You would typically add files that you need to include into the bundle and fetch them from the bundle.

Comment: Note that the bundle isn't "the current directory" - it is the application bundle file that is delivered from the App Store to the device.  It is actually a zip file.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the errors you get.

Comment: *"I want to check the files inside my Library folder that is in my project directory."* - The arbitrary folders you create for your project have nothing to do with the structure of the files built into the final app. Are the files in your Library folder even being bundled into the built app? Check the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase on the "Build Phases" tab of your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inspect the files in your Assets a.k.a. Ressources folder, do this:

```
let assetFolderUrl = Bundle.main.resourceURL
print(assetFolderUrl?.absoluteString)
do {
    if let assetFolderUrl {
        let itemsInDirectory = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetFolderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        print(itemsInDirectory)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

When dealing with files on disk, it is always a good idea to handle the errors. Also bear in mind that the results vary if you are sandboxed or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to modify your code to match my needs.